# Storing data on local storage or server page using javascript

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm developing an app for android & I'm gonna use PhoneGap.
As I already know PhoneGap or Cordova supports only HTML & JS, no server side language. I'm a bit well-versed with PHP, but unfortunately phone gap won't support it. So plz suggest some method using which I could store user data either on the user's local mobile storage or on a page over the internet..

Comment: js on server side?? NodeJS?

Comment: Is NodeJS supported by PhoneGap?

Comment: yes it is.. but if you want to have your backend/service layer written in some other language, you could do so as well..!! Check my answer if it is feasible

Answer (score 1):

To answer, ***some method using which I could store user data either on the user's local mobile***, use [PhoneGap local Storage API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0rc1/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#localStorage)

> The `window.localStorage` interface is based on the W3C [Web Storage interface](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0rc1/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage). An app can use it to save persistent data using key-value pairs. The `window.sessionStorage` interface works the same way, but all data is cleared each time the app closes

To answer, ***some method using which I could store user data on a page over the internet*** , You can use JS frameworks like `Angular` or `jQuery` or anything to make `http` calls to your server API(s) which could effectively be written in any language that supports data retrieval, and sending back an http response to the callee. In your case, it can be `PHP`. Phonegap is an independent client.

If the user data retrieved is light, just use the local storage API as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `localStorage` which will stick to the browser.

Snippet:

```
localStorage.setItem(name, value);
localStorage.getItem(name);
```